# D3.js: Update graph with changing data

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, get

I have a web scraper which gets minute-by-minute stock data and I'm trying to update my graph after every AJAX call. My x-axis and y-axis successfully redraw but I can't seem to get the area under my main path and my moving average line to update. Both lines transition but just form a  line along the top and the area doesn't seem to move at all.

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to do is to add a new datapoint, pop off the oldest datapoint with `data_prices.shift()` and then redraw the lines and area.

I'm not sure if my issue is with just a poor understanding of `enter()`, `update` and `exit()` but I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

The code I have for updating the graph post-AJAX call is below:

```
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("Success");
                console.log(data);
                if (data['pagedata']!=null) {
                    for(result in data['pagedata']) {
                        var item = {'timestamp':data['pagedata'][result][0], 
                                         'close':data['pagedata'][result][1], 
                                         'high':data['pagedata'][result][2], 
                                         'low':data['pagedata'][result][3], 
                                         'open':data['pagedata'][result][4], 
                                         'volume':data['pagedata'][result][5], 
                                         'average':data['pagedata'][result][6]}
                        if(!data_prices.includes(item)) {
                            data_prices.push(item);
                            data_prices.shift();
                        }
                    }

                    var prices = d3.keys(data_prices[0]).filter(function(d){
                        return d == "close" || d == "high" || d == "low" || d=="average";
                    });

                    prices.forEach(function(price){     
                        var g = focus.selectAll("g."+price);
                        var ctx = context.selectAll("g."+price);

                        var arr = data_prices.map(function(d){
                            return {
                                key: price,
                                timestamp: d.timestamp,
                                volume: d.volume,
                                value: d[price]
                            };
                        });

                        x.domain([d3.min(data_prices, function(d){
                            var time = timeParser(d.timestamp);
                            return time;
                        }), d3.max(data_prices, function(d){
                            var time = timeParser(d.timestamp);
                            return time;
                        })]);
                        y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([minVal, maxVal]).nice();

                        focus.select(".axis.x")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .call(xAxis);

                        focus.select(".axis.y")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .call(yAxis);

                        g.selectAll(".area")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                return area(d);
                            });

                        ctx.selectAll(".area")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                return areaCtx(d);
                            });

                        ctx.selectAll(".trendline")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                return lineCtx(d);
                            });

                        g.selectAll(".trendline")
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                console.log(d);
                                return line([arr]);
                            })
                            .attr("transform", null)
                                .transition()
                                    .duration(750)
                                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(-1) + ",0)")

                        ctx.selectAll(".avgLine")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                return lineCtx(d);
                            });

                        g.selectAll(".avgLine")
                            .transition()
                            .duration(750)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                                return line(d);
                            });

                    });
                }
            })
```

**UPDATE:** When I put `console.log(d);` into one of the `attr` sections for trendline etc, the dataset doesn't seem to update. So I think the issue is that I'm not updating the dataset and it's sort of freaking out?

Comment: can you share a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: An function of `d` would indicate a call to the data joined to the selection, but there is no data join in your update.  So, alternatively you can just update the line with the data assuming the line and area functions are set up properly.  I think you can just call `line(data)` for the `.attr("d")` for the line and so forth.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that since its a full app, but I've attached a jsfiddle which at least shows the js files. https://fiddle.jshell.net/2vwp1zuu/3/

Comment: That error just suggests the line isn't getting calculated correctly due to the line function not being properly defined or the data not being properly passed to the function.

Comment: @RyanMorton So I tried what you said, it doesn't throw any errors but the behaviour of the line itself is still the same.

Comment: Generally, when I write these types of charts, I use the same drawing function upon initialization as I do for the ongoing update.  Your code seems to data join upon initialization and no data join upon update.

Comment: I thought attaching data was a thing done on entry, that could very well be the issue. What would be the syntax for doing the same on update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165247/discussion-between-kuomi-and-ryan-morton).